# Carousel in IE10

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the [Cloud Carousel](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm) on a website. It works fine for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9 or lower, but for some reason in IE10 the carousel does not appear.

I've tried updating to the latest version. The code makes the carousel items hidden before showing them when all images are loaded. I wonder if something has changed in IE10 that prevents these items from showing?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me in IE10 desktop. Are there any errors in your console? Try running without cache and see if the problem persists

Comment: Loads fine for me as well Windows 7 + IE10 desktop

Comment: It works fine for me too win8 + IE10...Try clearing cache!

Comment: You are, of course, all right. Thanks for looking, a cache clear fixed it.